# Python 3.x sort filenames that contains numeric and letters in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have the following python code to sort a list of filenames

```
list_of_dwg = [
    r'\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-10.dwg',
    r'\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-11A.dwg',
    r'\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-4.dwg',
    r'\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-1_FRONT COVER.dwg',
    r'\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-2_MASTER LIST.dwg',
    r'\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-3_LEGEND LIST.dwg',

]

list_of_dwg_sorted = sorted(list_of_dwg)

for dwg in list_of_dwg_sorted:
    print(dwg)
```

When I execute the code, the output would look like this

```
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-10.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-11A.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-1_FRONT COVER.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-2_MASTER LIST.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-3_LEGEND LIST.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-4.dwg
```

But this is my ideal output based on the windows explorer display

```
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-1_FRONT COVER.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-2_MASTER LIST.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-3_LEGEND LIST.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-4.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-10.dwg
\\pc_name\AHL-4604-0002-11A.dwg
```

Any idea would be a great help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strings are sorted literally, you need to use the integer value of a digit to sort them based on their value.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort digit strings based on their values you should use their integer value because strings are sorted literally which means that for example the string `10` is smaller than `2`.

The `sorted()` function accepts a key function that you can use to tell `sorted` how sorts your items. In this case we can use regular expression to find the latest number in your file names and use its integer value to sort the items.

```
In [18]: import re

In [19]: def keyfunc(item):
    ...:     return int(re.search(r'-(\d+)[^-]*$', item).group(1))
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [20]: sorted(list_of_dwg, key=keyfunc)
Out[20]: 
['\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-1_FRONT COVER.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-2_MASTER LIST.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-3_LEGEND LIST.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-4.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-10.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-11A.dwg']
```

As you can see, in `keyfunc` we assumed that there is always a match for our regex without handling any possible exception and/or taking other factors into account for sorting. A proper way for handling these kinds of cases is to use a `try-except` in order to handle different exceptions in a proper way.

As an example, let's say that we want to sort the items just literally as default, in cases that our regular expression can't find the expected integer at the end of the file name. In that case, the code will return `AttributeError` because `re.search()` will return None and None object doesn't have the `group()` attribute. We can handle this situation simply as following:

```
In [21]: def keyfunc(item):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         return int(re.search(r'-(\d+)[^-]*$', item).group(1))
    ...:     except AttributeError:
    ...:         return item
```

Comment: Very informative and it works for me. Thanks a lot Kasramvd and to Paul Panzer also for the time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a key function that should be able to deal with more or less any string:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> def key_fun(s):
...     return (*(("",) if s and s[0].isdecimal() else ()), *(int(''.join(g)) if k else ''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(s, str.isdecimal)),)
```

Demo (added a few random strings, that don't follow the pattern):

```
>>> pprint(sorted(list_of_dwg + ['', '45', 'e'], key=key_fun))
['',
 '45',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-1_FRONT COVER.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-2_MASTER LIST.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-3_LEGEND LIST.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-4.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-10.dwg',
 '\\\\pc_name\\AHL-4604-0002-11A.dwg',
 'e']
```

Here is what the key function does. It groups by decimal/non decimal and converts the decimal blocks. One gotcha is that we must make sure we always start with the same kind of block because Python3 doesn't like comparing numbers and strings. I chose to prepend an empty string when the first character is a decimal. As a consequence everything that starts with a number comes before everything that starts with a non number.

```
>>> key_fun(list_of_dwg[0])
('\\\\pc_name\\AHL-', 4604, '-', 2, '-', 10, '.dwg')
```